# Is there any suitable answer among these options?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

I have just seen this questions in an exercise book for high school students.  And l am not sure if the options are really suitable.

I haven't seen my cousin in England for five years. I'm sure she........ a lot.

a. will grow b. will be growing c. will have grown d. will have been grown

My questions is, is there any suitable answer among these options? Isn't it correct to use "has grown"?

Comment: c) will have grown

Comment: If we are to choose between 'will have grown' and 'has grown', which one fits the context ?

Comment: "has grown" was not one of the choices, so why are you asking? You seem to be assuming that none of the choices work. It depends on the context, which I assume there is none. However, it looks like  your text is testing on future constructions. So while "has grown" may be a viable alternative, it was not a choice...

Comment: I think MM is asking whether *will have grown* is truly a valid option or whether it is just the best of a bad bunch, the correct answer being *has grown*. If so, I'd say *will have grown* is perfectly valid. *Will* is not only used to talk about the future - here it is used to make a conjecture, as in *they left half an hour ago, so they'll be there by now*.

Comment: @CascabIe: l didn't say that 'will have grown' is incorrect. I was just suggesting a better option 'has grown'. Actually, l wanted someone to agree on my suggestion.

Comment: I am wondering why the downvote.

Answer (score -3):

'Has grown' fits the context better. You are saying that you haven't seen your cousin for a period of five years. So in that period, she has grown a lot, hence you use the present perfect. 'Will have grown' is a period in the future, which is possible but makes less sense in this context since you are certain that she has grown a lot CURRENTLY and not IN 5 years. However, if you want to stress the message that by the time you see her again, she will have grown, which is a prediction, then it is possible. This is however not as obvious as simply using the present perfect, which stresses the period starting in the past to now, because you mentioned 'five years'.

Using the future perfect makes more sense if you want to convey a different message, in this case:
"I am going to meet my sister in five years, I am sure she will have grown a lot".

You make a prediction that she has grown a lot in the upcoming period in the future. So you shift the period to the future, hence the future perfect tense.

Edit: Using the future perfect is still possible, but the present perfect is more suitable in this context.

Comment: That’s not what the future means in this case. It makes perfect sense here, though the simple present perfect would be more common.

Comment: Care to explain?

Comment: By the time we see her again, she will have grown a lot.  This is a prediction.

Comment: Alright I understand the reasoning and that the future perfect is possible. I still think that the present perfect makes more sense.

Comment: @Stallmp The future can be used to make ‘predictions’ about the present. If you’re calculating or predicting how something is now based on past facts or experiences, you can use the future (or sometimes the conditional if you’re less sure about your ‘prediction’). You could also say, for example, “I haven’t seen her since she was a baby; she’ll (_or_ she’d) be about twenty now”.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I realised. Thanks.